# Can a "with" statement be used conditionally?

Tags: python, contextmanager

I have a Python function of roughly the following structure, that computes some results and writes them to a file:

```
results = []
with open(filename, "w") as output:
    for item in items:
        result = compute_stuff(item)
        write_result(item, result, output)
        results.append(result)
return results
```

Now I don't always want to write the results to file - sometimes I only want to compute them and have them returned. Making "write_result" conditional is easy, but is there also a way to make the file creation in the "with" statement condition-dependent? (I know I could handle opening and closing of the file explicitly, but I would incur the "try/finally" overhead that the "with" statement was created to avoid.)

Is there an elegant solution for this?

*Edited to add:*
I may have oversimplified the example. Instead of writing to an arbitrary file, I'm using `matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf.PdfPages` ([link](http://matplotlib.org/api/backend_pdf_api.html#matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf.PdfPages)), and adding a plot (new page in the PDF) in every step. In particular, that means I cannot re-open the PDF file with `PdfPages`, because it would be overwritten.

Comment: Could you split the logic into two steps (1. build the list; 2. write the list)?

Comment: +1 @Don. You already have a function `write_result`. Move the `with`-statement there.

Comment: You can use a coroutine as a sink instead of using a context manager. Look at this: http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/index.html

Comment: @Don: In the example yes, but I'm actually creating a complex plot in every step, so I'd have to keep track of a lot of data. I assume it would still be manageable, but I'm curious if there might be a nicer solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can write your own context manager function:

```
class Dummysink(object):
    def write(self, data):
        pass # ignore the data
    def __enter__(self): return self
    def __exit__(*x): pass

def datasink(filename):
    if filename:
        return open(filename, "w")
    else:
        return Dummysink()

...

results = []
with datasink(filename) as output:
    for item in items:
        result = compute_stuff(item)
        write_result(item, result, output)
        results.append(result)
return results
```

Comment: Bad solution because the with block is executed anyway

Comment: @pbacterio This is negligible compared to the benefit of simplicity.

Comment: If you want a dummy file object then `open(os.devnull)` is better than inventing your own, isn't it?

Comment: @SteveJessop Depends. As writing to `os.devnull` still involves system calls, it might be inferior to other solutions.

Comment: @glglgl: fair enough. I guess it depends in part how big the interface is that `write_result` uses. Somewhere between spotting a performance difference and implementing `tell()` you might decide the performance difference isn't such a big deal after all ;-)

Comment: This works and is relatively transparent, although a little more involved than I'd prefer. Accepted answer - thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need to pass in a function into the scope which encapsulates the fact that you might or might not want to store the results into a file. In OO languages this would be called a Strategy pattern but in Python you can just pass in a function (since functions are first class.)

```
my_gen = (compute_stuff(item) for item in items)
results = store_strategy(my_gen)
return results
```

Wherein `store_strategy` could just be something that already has the `with` statement within it or not.

```
def pass_through(iterable):
    return iterable

def file_store(filename):
    def store(items):
        with open(filename, 'w') as output:
            results = []
            for item in items:
                write_result(item, result, output)
                result.append(item)
        return results
    return store
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a helper function to wrap the real `open()` which either calls the real `open()` or which returns an object that has the methods `write()`, `flush()` and `close()`:

```
class MockFile(object):
    def write(self, data): pass
    def flush(self): pass
    def close(self): pass

def optionalWrite(filename, mode):
    if writeForRead: # <--- Your condition here
        return open(filename, mode)

    return MockFile()

with optionalWrite as output:
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Most, if not all, of the other answers describe how to write a context manager that would allow you to do what you want. Here's something a little different that directly addresses your question:

> *Can a “with” statement be used conditionally?*

Yes, it can — by using a [generator function](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#index-43) in conjunction with a `for` loop that conditionally doesn't iterate. Here's a runnable example based on the code in your question showing what I mean:

```
# Scaffolding added for testing.
def compute_stuff(item):
    return 'item: ' + str(item)

def write_result(item, result, output):
    output.write(result + '\n')

# Generator function.
def conditionally_with(filename, mode='r'):
    if not filename:  # Check condition.
        return
    else:
        with open(filename, mode) as opened:
            yield opened

if __name__ == '__main__':

    filename = 'foobar.txt'
    items = range(5)
    results = []

    for output in conditionally_with(filename, "w"):
        for item in items:
            result = compute_stuff(item)
            write_result(item, result, output)
            results.append(result)

    print(results)  # -> ['item: 0', 'item: 1', 'item: 2', 'item: 3', 'item: 4']
    # return results
```

Comment: I admit that I haven't tried it, but I like this answer because it's short and quite clear. The one downside is that replacing the "with" with a "for" may seem confusing at first.

Comment: Hendrik: I agree that using `for` instead of `with` seems a little odd -- however it makes it possible to have the indented "suite" of statements beneath, it as well as allowing any opened-file context a chance to exit following the single iteration.

Comment: Hendrik: Just watched this: [pyvideo.org/video/880/stop-writing-classes](http://pyvideo.org/video/880/stop-writing-classes) -- food for thought.

Comment: Wouldn't [`contextlib.contextmanager`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager) be much clearer here?  Your `conditionally_with` function would be written the same, and you wouldn't have the `for`/`with` syntax impedance mismatch.

Comment: @Sam: Valid point. I didn't specifically because my goal was to avoid unconditionally creating an extra context manager in order to avoid creating an additional one when a file was opened. Actually at this point I believe wheaties' Strategy Pattern idea achieves that the best.

Answer (score 1):

***Using coroutines***

http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/Coroutines.pdf (as suggested by Paulo Scardine)

If we want to write:

```
def writer(filename):
  with open(filename, "w") as output:
    while True:
      try:
        item, result = (yield)
        write_result(item, result, output)
      except GeneratorExit:
        output.flush()
        break
```

If we don't:

```
def dummy_writer():
   while True:
     yield
```

Initialize our coroutine:

```
result_writer = writer(filename) if filename else dummy_writer()
result_writer.next()
```

Run our code:

```
results = []
for item in items:
    result = compute_stuff(item)
    result_writer.send((item, result))
    results.append(result)
result_writer.close()
return results
```

Comment: Overkill for this task IMHO. Approach in search of a problem? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here's something derived from the suggestion in [wheaties' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22226844/355230) which I think may be the best context-manager-free approach (and so deserves example code which illustrates it more concretely):

```
def create_list():
    return list

def file_store(filename, mode='w'):
    def store(items):
        with open(filename, mode) as output:
            results = []
            for item in items:
                write_result(item, output)
                results.append(item)
        return results
    return store

store_strategy = file_store(filename) if filename else create_list()
results = store_strategy(compute_stuff(item) for item in items)
return results
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is cause late creation of the file. What you want is something that looks like a context manager, but doesn't actually create the file until you need it. You'll need to implement `__enter__` and `__exit__` yourself. This is a (very) abbreviated example, compare to a full one, just for your exact case:

```
class LateFile(object):
    def __init__(self, filename, mode):
        self.filename = filename
        self.mode = mode
        self.fp = None

    def __enter__(self):
        # Do nothing - we don't open the file yet
        return(self)

    def __exit__(self, exctype, value, traceback):
        if self.fp != None:
            fp.close()

    def write(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.fp == None:
            self.fp = open(self.filename, self.mode)
        self.fp.write(*args, **kwargs)
```

Something along those lines.

And then, to use it, do something like:

```
with LateFile(filename, "w") as output:
    for item in items:
        result = compute_stuff(item)
        if should_write_result(item, result):
            write_result(item, result, output)
        results.append(result)
```

`write_result` should see `output` as a normal file object; you'll need to reflect or delegate the methods down to it. Doing this, if no results are written, the file will not be created, but if even one result is written, the file will be created & written to.

Comment: A "do nothing" function would at least have to contain a `pass` statement -- although that doesn't really apply in this case because `__enter__()` needs to `return self` so a later `output.write()` doesn't result in an `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'` exception.

Comment: Nice solution, but doesn't fit the question: _Now I don't always want to write the results to file - sometimes I only want to compute them and have them returned._

Comment: why not? the usage always computes the results (it is modifying `results`). however, it will only create a file if you actually choose to write one of those result pieces.

Comment: IMO it's not wrong. It's more flexible than the questioner asked for, I didn't get any impression that the result of `should_write_result` depends on the item. That's not a bad thing, the questioner is unlikely to be somehow mislead into writing more code than needed, I think :-)